# VBA - Find string from beginning

Tags: excel, vba, find

I need to find a string "c =", and the cell that I'm looking for, has the value of "c = 0.32".
The problem is that in the same range, I have a cell with the value of "blablac = 54", which comes first, and the

```
Dim x as Integer
x = Find("c =", MatchCase:=True).row
```

function, returns that one instead of the "c = 0.32" one.
How can I tell the find function to look for the string in the beginning of the cell values, so that I can obtain the right value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcard `What:="c =*"` and use `LookAt:=xlWhole` (for matching entire word). In that case `Find` will return only cells, which values starts from `c =`:

```
Dim x As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Find(What:="c =*", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    x = rng.Row
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Instr` instead. That gives you the position of the first occurrence of a string.

In your case, `Instr(<string>, "=")` gives you the position of `=`. You can then use `Left`, `Mid` and `Right` to extract the portions the string you want.

Obviously, case is no longer relevant and you can use `trim` to remove any spaces around `=`.